# Google Maps API in ASP.NET Masterpage: why it stays blank?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps

This simple example works in pure html when launching within visual studio localhost:port  server

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<style type="text/css">
  html { height: 100% }
  body { height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px }
  #map_canvas { height: 100% }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        myOptions);
    }

</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to adapt to asp.net under visual studio 2010 default template and though it runs it doesn't show any map why ?

Masterpage:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Site.master.cs" Inherits="SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px }
      #map_canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function initialize() {
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: latlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            myOptions);
        }

    </script>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">

    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
    <form runat="server">
    <div class="page">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="title">
                <h1>
                    Google Maps in ASP.NET
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="loginDisplay">
                <asp:LoginView ID="HeadLoginView" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
                    <AnonymousTemplate>
                        [ <a href="~/Account/Login.aspx" ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server">Log In</a> ]
                    </AnonymousTemplate>
                    <LoggedInTemplate>
                        Welcome <span class="bold"><asp:LoginName ID="HeadLoginName" runat="server" /></span>!
                        [ <asp:LoginStatus ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log Out" LogoutPageUrl="~/"/> ]
                    </LoggedInTemplate>
                </asp:LoginView>
            </div>
            <div class="clear hideSkiplink">
                <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Items>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Home"/>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" Text="About"/>
                    </Items>
                </asp:Menu>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="main">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"/>
        </div>
        <div class="clear">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Default.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">

  <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>

</asp:Content>
```

Update: this is the rendered html

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head><title> 
    Home Page
</title><link href="Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
    <style type="text/css"> 
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px }
      #map_canvas { height: 100% }
    </style> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" /> 
    <script type="text/javascript"

        src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"> 
    </script> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        function initialize() {
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: latlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            myOptions);
        }

    </script> 


</head> 
<body onload="initialize()"> 
    <form method="post" action="default.aspx" id="ctl01"> 
<div class="aspNetHidden"> 
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUKMTY1NDU2MTA1MmRkgEGBoemMtm+/v6V+m9lmIvRj4NCUaPh/xvbFFRPTsmc=" /> 
</div> 


<script src="/googlemapstutorial/WebResource.axd?d=pX2KOH15DXBIWd9F3pw0pYRvxH0rCs_7BzgxTRUKsZkV8iILrBf16Um3jfikb78HXD5CWcorG2sj456pwVRsUev4lKFhNxwLEsZ0G3MsXkw1&amp;t=634222671270572046" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <div class="page"> 
        <div class="header"> 
            <div class="title"> 
                <h1> 
                    Google Maps in ASP.NET
                </h1> 
            </div> 
            <div class="loginDisplay"> 

                        [ <a href="Account/Login.aspx" id="HeadLoginView_HeadLoginStatus">Log In</a> ]

            </div> 
            <div class="clear hideSkiplink"> 
                <a href="#NavigationMenu_SkipLink"><img alt="Skip Navigation Links" src="/googlemapstutorial/WebResource.axd?d=TJBKVc8nekHCgPywjGbDmMgRlrAm9FIu3FELc6xCCTlRxYfnY8nfoPOyAs8B8fawdRaonWVsHF9mLU3lY2PCkgjBIN2S1Hne4nX1WfWtaN01&amp;t=634222671270572046" width="0" height="0" style="border-width:0px;" /></a><div class="menu" id="NavigationMenu"> 
    <ul class="level1"> 
        <li><a class="level1" href="Default.aspx">Home</a></li><li><a class="level1" href="About.aspx">About</a></li> 
    </ul> 
</div><a id="NavigationMenu_SkipLink"></a> 
            </div> 
        </div> 
        <div class="main"> 


  <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div> 


        </div> 
        <div class="clear"> 
        </div> 
    </div> 
    <div class="footer"> 

    </div> 

<script type='text/javascript'>new Sys.WebForms.Menu({ element: 'NavigationMenu', disappearAfter: 500, orientation: 'horizontal', tabIndex: 0, disabled: false });</script></form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: I think the issue is on <!DOCTYPE and you need to change a little the script code.

Comment: You're right I forgot so I corrected above but still blank.

Comment: dude - what the hell is this? => `<script type='text/javascript'>new Sys.WebForms.Menu({ element: 'NavigationMenu', disappearAfter: 500, orientation: 'horizontal', tabIndex: 0, disabled: false });</script>`

Comment: This is what i'm getting in my html for the map_canvas DIV: `  <div id="map_canvas" style="background-color: rgb(229, 227, 223); z-index: 0; overflow: hidden; position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>` **I don't know why** i'm getting this. If i turn off the `Position` and `overflow` params, it now shows.  .. hmmm ... Is this css getting inherited from google maps?

Comment: This css must come from the default web template in visual studio 2010 since it wasn't in the html source code.

Comment: new Sys.WebForms.Menu sure comes from visual studio 2010 web template for it creates a tabs menu.

Comment: Finally I have looked with firebug the original html source code, the css comes from Google.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google is all Javascript, so the fact it's in a Master page shouldn't matter unless you have local path issues, which I don't see.

I would use Firefox's Error Console to see if there are any Javascript errors when the page loads.

**EDIT**

I thought it was some weird tag nesting issue, but it's actually the fact that you're using percentages for your dimensions.  '100%' means use fill the enclosing containers space, but if the container is empty we don't get a size.  If you set your map div to a fixed size, you will see your map.

Comment: So I did it, there's no error. I have posted above the rendered html also above