# How to just deploy the Visual Studio 2010 ASP.NET website example to a remote dedicated web 2008 server?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis-7

I can't believe my eyes it's so hard to do just that ! Why can't I use MS Access instead of SQL Server Express ? So since I'm stucked with SQL Server Express, how can I make it work on my dedicated IIS 7 Server on Windows 2008 ?

I have copied under the root directory of the server. The website works until I try to login then I get:

> Failed to generate a user instance of
>   SQL Server

I cannot find a single article that just explains step by step how to deploy this simple example used by Microsoft or can I ? Then can you point me to this tutorial thanks.

Update: in case it does matter I have installed SQL Server 2008 Express Advance Services Edition.

Comment: Too little info. Need to know the protocol you're using. We use ODBC to attach to our servers.

Comment: You have all the info: just open VS 2O10 create an aspnet.net website from the standard template and upload to your webserver and you're done. It doesn't use ODBC of course but SQL server.

Comment: This depends on configuration of dev environment and VS2010 defaults

Answer (score 1):

**"Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment" [1]**

Plz check the enumeration of problems in "Problems using server-side Automation of Office" section of [1]

Had not I answered it [2a] in you previous question [2] that in order to deploy one should have managed something to deploy first, i.e. first manage to develop on developing machine targeting the same environment as target machine?

If you cannot manage to do it with SQL Express, you certainly wpuld not manage it with MS Access. It is more complocated and involved.

Update:
I still insist on my answers.
Deployment is not magic nor fortune teller, it will not correct your configuration errors or guess what you did not bother to formulate or even wish about.  **You confuse deployment with the necessity of configuration or even setups as well a knowing them**
You cannot deploy without configuring (or knowing) production and developing environments and properly formulating your objective (and question) accordingly.
Just because you do not know what you want, what you can and how does not mean that you cannot believe your eyes.

Cited:

CITED:
[1]
Considerations for server-side Automation of Office
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757

[2]
Why do “I get Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server” with .NET 4 and not .NET 2 ?
[Why do "I get Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server" with .NET 4 and not .NET 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901833/why-do-i-get-failed-to-generate-a-user-instance-of-sql-server-with-net-4-and-n)
[2a]
My answer to your question [2]
[Why do "I get Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server" with .NET 4 and not .NET 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901833/why-do-i-get-failed-to-generate-a-user-instance-of-sql-server-with-net-4-and-n/3902890#3902890)

Comment: My question is not about MS Access neither about .NET 2 vs .NET 4, my question is about how to deploy the standard VS 2010 asp.net website which uses SQL Server.

Answer (score -3):

OK guys I found one kind guru on ASP.NET forum who could answer to the question so never mind. For alone newbies like me it is due to context/user which was application pool identity which has no rights.

Comment: Post the answer you found, instead of writing "nevermind." Voted down.