# Problem with ASP.NET when using IsPostback + Properties + RegisterStartupScript + Google Maps API

Tags: asp.net, google-maps

After I successfully created my first google maps in asp.net with this question [Google Maps API in ASP.NET Masterpage: why it stays blank?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897781/google-maps-api-in-asp-net-masterpage-why-it-stays-blank)

I now want to change the maps lat, long when clicking with Go button. For this I just need to pass a new x,y at startupsctipt to GoogleMaps js function.

first load is ok, but it's no more OK on second load maps is empty, I can't see why:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{


    private String m_x;
    private String m_y;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String x;
        String y;

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {

            m_x = "48.854401";
            m_y = "2.316923";
        }


        String script = "GoogleMaps('" + m_x + "," + m_y + ")";
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "GoogleMaps", script, true);
    }

    protected void ButtonGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        m_x = "-34.397";
        m_y = "150.644";
    }
}
```

Comment: "Stackoverflow seems to be less and less frequented" > it sure is on weekends

Comment: Oh you're right as for me I mostly code on we during the week I'm just managing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `m_x` and `m_y` are set only on the first page load (`if(!IsPostBack)`), if you want to keep the values, save them in [viewstate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx) for example.

The event Page_Load happens before the Button_Click event. So the javascript is written before you set the values in the Button_Click. See this page for the order the events happen: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your remark: did you see they are also set in ButtonGo_Click ? that's where I want them to be taken into account when I click on this button.

Comment: @user310291 Goto have right, you use the m_x and m_y with out have set it first, I wondering why is not thow you an error.

Comment: @Aristos I made a debug and m_x contains null. OK thanks Goto I'll have to call from button too.